# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths on heavily-updated model crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

A view controller has a data model which updates constantly and aggressively

A UItableview  (storyTable) is called ever so often to update and reflect the changes to date.

(Changed the code to reflect only a single beginUpdates endUpdates) - still crashes

```
  [self.storyTable beginUpdates];
                if([deleteIndexPaths count]){
                    DLog(@"Table refresh delele rows :%@",deleteIndexPaths);

                    [self.storyTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


                }

                if ([addIndexPaths count]){
                    DLog(@"Table refresh add rows :%@",addIndexPaths);

                    [self.storyTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                }
                if ([changedIndexPaths count]){

                    DLog(@"Table refresh change rows :%@",changedIndexPaths);
                    [self.storyTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:changedIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade ];

                }
                [self.storyTable endUpdates];
                //[self.storyTable endUpdates];
                tableIsAnimating = NO;

        }
```

Crashes from time to time with the following message:
(mostly on deleteRowsAtIndexPaths...)

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (20) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (20), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   10 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

or :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 20
>   into section 0, but there are only 20 rows in section 0 after the
>   update'

**Question: How can one add some protective code to prevent the crash?**

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use `NSFetchedResultsController` and `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to show the model changes? Are you not using Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that when there are both deletes, adds and changes mixed at the same time, your indexPaths will be all wrong after first -endUpdates.

You can try this:

```
[self.storyTable beginUpdates];
if([deleteIndexPaths count]){
   [self.storyTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
if ([addIndexPaths count]){
   [self.storyTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
if ([changedIndexPaths count]){
   [self.storyTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:changedIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade ];
}
[self.storyTable endUpdates];
```

This way the indexPaths will be valid through all operations.

Comment: thank for the help, I did changed the code (see above) , still having an issue (app crashed)...

Comment: I'm sorry this did not solve your issue. In that case I don't have further ideas now.

Answer (score -2):

i think your tableview change not because you deleterowsatindexpath but reloaddata, in the other word using deleterowateindexpath do not do the basic deleting work.